# Fetching size of message using IMAP command

Tags: c#, imap

I am fetching the size of message using following IMAP command.

> "$ FETCH UID RFC822.SIZE\r\n"

For some messages the command works properly and returns the message size

> "* 3 FETCH (RFC822.SIZE 2376)\r\n$ OK Success\r\n"

But for some emails its not fetching the size of message. It returns only Success message but not the size

Here is the response for some messages.

> "$ OK Success\r\n"

Is there any alternative way for fetching the size of message?

Comment: Your command isn't legal. The real command has to include an argument to point to the message. What is the real command?

Comment: Actual command is:

"$ FETCH 1 RFC822.SIZE\r\n"

Comment: `$ FETCH N RFC822.SIZE\r\n` will fetch the size of the Nth message in the mailbox, not the message with a UID of N. If you want to fetch based on UID, then you need to use `UID FETCH N RFC822.SIZE\r\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping out on a limb... what you have in mind is `x uid fetch 1234 rfc822.size` in order to learn the size of the message with UID 1234. However, what you send is `y fetch 1234 rfc822.size`, and if there are fewer than 1234 messages in the mailbox that command will not work.

Am I guessing correctly?

Comment: Good catch! I did not notice that he wasn't using the proper syntax.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Its resolved the issue. Thank you arnt

Answer (score 0):

If you get no size information back, then it means that the message doesn't exist.

Comment: No. The message does exists. I am able to fetch the body and header of the same message

Comment: Technically it doesn't because you are requesting the size of a message at a specific *index* and not *uid*.